# How will this fare on this site?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question over on gamedev.SE, [Why don't I see tile-based 3D graphics? [closed]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169437/why-dont-i-see-tile-based-3d-graphics) which was closed as of-topic. It was not received well because it's not a question about an actual problem with a project that I've actually tried to implement. It's just preliminary research really.

But then I found that there's this site specifically for computer graphics. Great, I might just copy-paste that question over here. But first I just wanted to check that I don't misunderstand the ontopicness of this site also. So my question is, Is that question on-topic here?

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately that will be decided by the community, but after reading your question, it seems on-topic to me. It seems interesting to graphics practitioners and we definitely don't have the limitation here that questions have to be about code you're writing.

That said, if you do post it here (or ask for it to be migrated), I'd recommend adding the information that you want to write something similar yourself. You're more likely to receive answers helpful to you if answerers know the background and motivation of your question.